# How can I find a string between repeated strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string

How can I find a string between repeated strings?
For example, if

```
string str = @"||AAA||BBB||CCC||";
```

how can I find all the strings(AAA, BBB, CCC) in order between repeated strings(||)?

Comment: With a regex...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not that familiar with regular expressions, so would you please tell me how to?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: oh and does it also support unicodes?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Regex seems overkill for a simple string split don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `String.Split`:

```
var str = @"||AAA||BBB||CCC||";
var splits = str.Split(new string[] {"||"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```